# Convert vector of pointer to vector of objects

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have this vector:

```
std::vector<T*> foo;
```

I have a function with the following signature (I can not alter it):

```
void bar(std::vector<T> const&);
```

How Can I pass foo to that function with minimum changes?

My current approach is:

```
std::vector<T> another_bar(bar.size());
std::transform(std::begin(bar),std::end(bar),std::begin(another_bar),[](T* item){return *T;});
```

I think there is a lot of unnecessary copying is happening here.

**EDIT:**

T is not a templated parameter. It is a specified type.

Comment: What is `T`? A specific type or a template parameter?

Comment: There's copying, but I don't think it's unnecessary. How else could you obtain a `vector<T>`?

Comment: Why do you have vector of raw pointers in the first lace?

Comment: @Zulan: specific Type

Comment: @alcedine That exactly what I am asking for.

Comment: As @alcedine said, there's no way around that when trying to get `<T>`.

Comment: @LogicStuff let us assume it is something that I can not change for now

Comment: @HumamHelfawi right, and I'm telling you that if it does not contain a sequence of `T` objects one after the other, it is not a `vector<T>`. Unless you can be sure that the pointees in your `vector<T*>` already exist in such a contiguous manner somewhere (and in the correct order), you'll have to copy (though in that case, I don't know why you wouldn't be using that existing space to begin with).

Comment: `std::back_inserter` may help (and `std::vector::reserve` to avoid multiple allocation).

Comment: I think I know what @LogicStuff aimed at, if the vector contains pointers-to-baseclass, you have a big problem with slicing and your baseclass probably violates the so-called "Law of Three".

Comment: Is `T` cheap to move?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whereas you need to to some copies, you may avoid to construct default value and then create copy by direct copy construct:

```
std::vector<T> another_bar;
another_bar.reserve(bar.size());
std::transform(std::begin(bar), std::end(bar),
               std::back_inserter(another_bar),[](T* item){return *item;});
```

Comment: Yes that is better for sure.. However, I was thinking of totally better solution but it seems not exist. Thanks again

Comment: `[](T* item){return *T;}` should be corrected as `[](T* item){return *item;}` right?

Comment: @user3405291: sure, typo fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is as correct as possible.  You have to do a lot of copying.  Another problem is that it will also "slice" if you have any classes derived from T. Sometimes you have two dissimilar programs and it is unavoidable, but more likely you should reevaluate the design of either the caller or the function.

Comment: The notice about slicing is great! But then again, if `T` was a polymorphic base class, the `foo` signature wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: foo is fine for a base class.  It is the function call to bar that prevents polymorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Since `T` is a specific given type, there is no way to avoid the copy without modifying either `T` or `bar`.

If you can make `T` generic, you could create sort of a "PIMPL-wrapper": An object that internally contains a pointer to a real `T` and implements the same interface of `T` by calling the respective functions internally.

In other words, your transformation code looks good.